# Python 2.7 datetime object returning a value of 60 seconds

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I have the following bit of code I use to generate timestamps from a lot of instruments.  The data gets logged into an initial SQLite database when it is read (w/o milliseconds), then logged into a second database when it's transmitted (w. milliseconds).  After several days of data capture, I find that there are a couple times per night where I end up with a logged time that ends with 60 seconds (vs 00 or 59).

I understand that Python has some support for leap seconds, but I know that there weren't any during the nights I was recording data. Also, datetime doesn't support seconds greater than 59.  Anyway, I don't know what's going on, and I haven't been able to reproduce the problem by hand.  I was hoping someone else might have seen this behavior before.

So, as an example, in my first log I have the entry 20160823043460, and in my transmit log I have 20160823043500.01.

Here's my timestamp code.  (Yes, I know it's odd that everything doesn't get the same timestamp, but I  didn't design the spec, I'm just coding to it)

```
def makeTimeStamp(time=None, miliseconds=False):
    timeStamp = ""
    if time is None and miliseconds is False:
        timeStamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    #time format: YYYY MM DD HH MM SS as one string
    elif time is None and miliseconds is True:
        timeStamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f")
    else:
        try:
            timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        except AttributeError:
            print "error:  attempted to make a timestamp from a " + type(time)
    return timeStamp
```

Comment: Thank you, that is easier to read.

Comment: Are you calling your function with time=None, and storing the returned string as a string and not a number? You say you store it in sqlite. What is the datatype of the column? Also, consider renaming the 'time' argument as there is a module in the standard lib with that name, that happens to also have a 'strftime()' function.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So that is a poor choice of name on my part.  I don't know why I picked that, but it's a place to pass in a datetime created somewhere else.  In this case, I'm not using it at all, time is always None.

Comment: What goes into SQLite is the string returned by strftime. I understand that strftime is allowed to return strings where seconds=60, but I'm seeing that behavior far more often that I should.  I'll rerun some of this code again next week to see if I can generate the behavior again.

Answer (score -1):

Check python docs for time library, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

In the notes, under 2, it says that the range for seconds is really [0, 61].

Comment: Understood.  However, the docs say that the 60 and 61 are for leap seconds, which didn't occur while I was logging.  I feel like this is a rounding error, but I'm surprised to see it in a base Python library.

Comment: OP says he is not unsing the time package but datetime, that does not do leap seconds according to the docs.

Comment: Look closely at the else part of the code: `timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

Comment: @Fejs No, 'time' is not the time module but the first argument to the function.